# How do I beat Dahaka in Final Fantasy 13?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

Every time I attempt this boss battle I quickly die (in about 10 minutes).  How do I beat Dahaka?

Comment: Somebody posted a helpful link as an answer, but then mods convinced them to delete it.  I don't know the answer, but I think the link may help.  You can't see that deleted answer because you don't have enough rep, but here it is.  http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100311125322AAJb9Y0

Answer (score 1):

The key to Dahaka is appropriately buffing your own party while also debuffing him.

Dahaka is susceptible to Deprotect (1.89x physical damage), Imperil (2x elemental damage), and Slow (50% atb rate). Your party should have Haste on all members and Bravery/Faith and any elemental Enspell (Enwater, Enfire, etc) to take advantage of Imperil.

An easy party to achieve this is Sazh, Vanille, Fang.